# How to get more space by manually deleting unnecessary system files (rooted S2)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.1-jelly-bean, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I keep getting warning that apps cannot be installed on their default location since there is too little space.

However, when I check in system there is a bunch of space, especially for small apps of a few MBs.

[image: SD card] [image: System space]
<sup>Screenshots (click for larger variants)</sup>

I tried moving some apps on SD card, but again I got a message that there is not space available.

Is there some system space occupied by unnecessary files which I can manually delete?

Or other way to solve this silly bug?

This is Galaxy S2 with official 4.1 OS. I have root access (rooted phone).

Comment: Please check if our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) might help you on this. The error usually points to internal storage only, so non of your SD cards (neither internal nor external) should be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy)'s suggestions, I also find [Clean Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en) helpful in cleaning unecessary files / cache. Check it out. :)

Comment: does it clean system folders as well (only for rooted devices)?

Comment: @AnDroDroo I am not sure, but maybe NO.